# CSS file is not linking via <% include file.ejs %>

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs

I have a file **header.ejs** that contains a head tag with all script & link tags and a navbar.
Another file **footer.ejs** contains some divs and the closing tag **i.e. /html**.
I am trying to add these to other ejs files using : **<%include file.ejs %>**.
While this works on one file **campground.ejs**, the css doesn't seem to be linked on another **entry.ejs**.

The **header/footer** are in **project/views/partials** and the **campground/entry** are in **project/views**. The **stylesheet** is in **project/resources**; **project** being the root folder of the work.

Both files(campgrounds/entry) follow the same structure:

```
<%include partials/header%>
  <div>

       ---some code---

  </div>
<%include partials/footer%>
```

The stylesheet is linked to the header perfectly, which works as expected in the **campground.ejs**. But there is no styling in the **entry.ejs**, while the bootstrap(linked in **header.ejs**) works just fine.

Comment: Is the URL referring to the Bootstrap CSS valid or accessible? Else have a try using the CDN link: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I am using a CDN link, which works fine with both my files

Comment: I have a temporary fix. I was using get request on "/campground" for my campground and "/campground/new" for entry. When I changed the get req to "/entry" for entry.ejs, the css was linked correctly. Though it works, I would like to know why it didn't in the first place.